# Get result of a function before continue with the script

Tags: javascript

I was trying to use vanilla JS to recreate the "prompt" function, where an input text appears, the user type something and, after, an "alert" shows the text typed.

But I'm really stuck - how can I receive the typed text to send an alert after.

Considering that the alert will be out of the prompt function, just like it would be if I'd use the native solution.

```js
function nativePrompt(message) {
  var greeting = prompt(message);
  return greeting
}

function recievedMessage(message) {
var message = nativePrompt(message);
alert(message);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="recievedMessage('Say Hi')">Native Prompt</button>
```

Here's where I am:

```js
function myPrompt(message) {

  var wrap = document.createElement('div');
 wrap.setAttribute("id", "wrap");
  
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute("id","input");
  input.setAttribute("type","text");
  
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.setAttribute("id","button");
  button.innerHTML = "OK";
  button.onclick = function() {
    result = document.getElementById('input').value;
    document.getElementById('wrap').remove();
    return result;
  }
  
  wrap.innerHTML = message;
  wrap.appendChild(input);
  wrap.appendChild(button);
  
  document.body.appendChild(wrap);

}

function receiveResult() {
var result = myPrompt("Say Hi!!");
alert(result);
}
```

```css
#wrap {
width:100%;
height:60px;
background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="receiveResult()">Show My Prompt</button>
```

Note that the function `recieveResult` should alert the return of the myPrompt function. But it returns undefined because the script goes on before the return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding some event handling concepts. `return result;` inside the click handler does not actually return the result to anywhere meaningful.

So this line `var result = myPrompt("Say Hi!!");` does not actually return what's written inside your custom prompt.
You need to get and alert the value of the input box inside the ok button click event, instead of returning it.

```js
function myPrompt(message) {

  var wrap = document.createElement('div');
 wrap.setAttribute("id", "wrap");
  
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute("id","input");
  input.setAttribute("type","text");
  
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.setAttribute("id","button");
  button.innerHTML = "OK";
  button.onclick = function() {
    result = document.getElementById('input').value;
    document.getElementById('wrap').remove();
    alert( result );
    // do the alert here instead of inside the other function
    // would be wise to rename both functions.
  }
  
  wrap.innerHTML = message;
  wrap.appendChild(input);
  wrap.appendChild(button);
  
  document.body.appendChild(wrap);

}

function receiveResult() {
  myPrompt("Say Hi!!");
  // var result won't be available here.
}
```

```css
#wrap {
width:100%;
height:60px;
background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="receiveResult()">Show My Prompt</button>
```

---

**Using a callback:**

```js
function renderPrompt(message,callback) {

  var wrap = document.createElement('div');
 wrap.setAttribute("id", "wrap");
  
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute("id","input");
  input.setAttribute("type","text");
  
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.setAttribute("id","button");
  button.innerHTML = "OK";
  button.onclick = function handleClick() {
    result = document.getElementById('input').value;
    document.getElementById('wrap').remove();
    callback( result );
    // Call the callback we received to pass the result back.
  }
  
  wrap.innerHTML = message;
  wrap.appendChild(input);
  wrap.appendChild(button);
  
  document.body.appendChild(wrap);

}

function page1Prompt() {
  renderPrompt("Say Hi!!", function( result ) {
    alert( result );
  });
  // var result won't be available here.
}
// You can now pass different functions to renderPrompt() to reuse the function.
function page2Prompt() {
  renderPrompt("Say Hi!!", function( result ) {
    alert( 'the other page also has a result: ' + result );
    console.log( result );
    // someOtherFunctionThatMightNeedResult( result );
  });
}
```

```css
#wrap {
width:100%;
height:60px;
background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="page1Prompt()">Show My Prompt for Page 1</button>
<button onclick="page2Prompt()">Show My Prompt for Page 2</button>
```

Comment: Got it! But I'd like to use the same code to others situations. For example: One page calls the myPrompt to alert... Another one, calls the myPrompt to use the typed text as url for an ajax call... So, I'd have to rewrite the function for each situation?

Comment: Read up on event handlers, since this is a very common situation. The simplest solution is passing a callback together with the message. I post an example.

Comment: Updated with a second example. In reality you're probably going to use more complex messaging systems between event handlers and the result of the program, but this should suffice to see the idea.